# Calling different UIView .xibs in a UIView contained in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIView (containingView) inside a UIViewController (onboardingViewController).

I have 3 xibs that are UIViews and I want to sequentially call each xib UIView into the containingView that is placed in the onboardingViewController.

So my question is that, how do I reference each xib to call show it in containingView?

I've tried placing the views in an array and then add them to the subview of containingView but I am not able to view them when I run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you first want to load the views from your xib files programmatically and add them to your `containerView`.

```
// Load the UIViews from your Xib files
UIView *view1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView1" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
UIView *view2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView2" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
UIView *view3 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView3" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

// Now that you have references to your xibs, add them as subviews to your containingView
[containingView addSubview:view1];
[containingView bringSubviewToFront:view1];

// repeat as you need to load views 2 and 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
Should I then override the drawRect for setting up my subviews? If so, do I call the drawRect method after i add the subview to the container view?
Sorry for any ignorance on my part - I am still learning iOS

Comment: You shouldn't need to override `drawRect`.  You may need to adjust the frame of your `UIViews` if they don't fit into your `containerView` properly.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm going to try and use this and get back to you if there's any issue. If that's okay?

Comment: Sure!  Please feel free to follow up with any questions.